# Ignore error when importing JSON files in R

Tags: r, try-catch, jsonlite

I have this `for` loop that download a json file from a `solr` search server.
It loops over a vector that contain keywords (100, in this case):

```
library(jsonlite)
for (i in 1:100) {
  docs <- fromJSON(paste("http://myurl.com/solr/select?df=topic&fq=",keywords[i],"&indent=on&q=*:*&rows=1&wt=json",sep=""))
  numFound <- docs$response$numFound
  print(numFound)
}
```

It works fine, until it reaches a certain keyword that is not found on the solr, and returns this error:

```
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 400.
```

And then the loop stops.

Is there a way to ignore the error and proceed the loop?

I've read something using `tryCatch` but still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler than `tryCatch`, you can use the function `try` inside your keyword loop. This will attempt to load the URL, but if an error is encountered will print the error but continue to the next keyword.

```
library(jsonlite)
for (i in 1:100) {
  try({
    docs <- fromJSON(paste("http://myurl.com/solr/select?df=topic&fq=",keywords[i],"&indent=on&q=*:*&rows=1&wt=json",sep=""))
    numFound <- docs$response$numFound
    print(numFound)
  })
}
```

If you also don't want to have the errors printed, specify `silent = TRUE`:

```
library(jsonlite)
for (i in 1:100) {
  try({
    docs <- fromJSON(paste("http://myurl.com/solr/select?df=topic&fq=",keywords[i],"&indent=on&q=*:*&rows=1&wt=json",sep=""))
    numFound <- docs$response$numFound
    print(numFound)
  }, silent = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to purrr's `safely` for this kind of task, which works well in purrr's map functions. You can test it by getting JSONs from GitHub's API:

```r
keywords <- c("hadley", "gershomtripp", "lsjdflkaj")
url <- "https://api.github.com/users/{.}/repos"
```

Now we can get the JSONs and extract the repo IDs

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(glue)

json_list <- map(keywords, safely(~ fromJSON(glue(url)) %>% .$id))
```

This will return a list of elements containing `result` and `error`. If there was an error it will be saved in `error`, otherwise the results will be save in `result`.

```r
[[1]]
[[1]]$result
 [1]  40423928  40544418  14984909  12241750   5154874   9324319  20228011     82348    888200   3116998
[11]   8296284 137344416 133734429   2788278  28724058   9470424 116708612  34325557     41144     41157
[21]  78543290  66588778  35225488  14507273  15718805  18562209     12522 115742443 119107571    201908

[[1]]$error
NULL


[[2]]
[[2]]$result
 [1] 150995700 141743224 127107806 130802586 185857872 131488780 148619375 165221804 135417803 127116088
[11] 181662388 173351888 127131146 136896011

[[2]]$error
NULL


[[3]]
[[3]]$result
NULL

[[3]]$error
<simpleError in open.connection(con, "rb"): HTTP error 404.>
```